# How do I reverse the order of log entries in this file? (Vim for preference)

Tags: vim, emacs, regex, text-editors

I've got a set of files that contain notes written in reverse order:

```
###### 27/07/2016-15:04:20 GMT+1:
Really? More? 

###### 27/07/2016-15:04:18 GMT+1:
It happened again! 

###### 27/07/2016-15:04:16 GMT+1:
A thing happened
```

I'd like them to appear in this order:

```
###### 27/07/2016-15:04:16 GMT+1:
A thing happened

###### 27/07/2016-15:04:18 GMT+1:
It happened again! 

###### 27/07/2016-15:04:20 GMT+1:
Really? More?
```

Some of these files have  couple of hundred entries - what's the easiest way of making this happen?

Comment: The linux 'tac' command ('cat' backwords) will print out all of the lines reversed but then your groups would be reversed also. (Message after date)

Answer (score 3):

#### Only tac

The command `tac` can do it.

```
$ tac -b -s "######" file.log
```

#### Call tac by Vim

If you want run it in Vim:

```
:%!tac -b -s "\#\#\#\#\#\#"
```

`%` means all lines.

`!` runs [external command](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Use_filter_commands_to_process_text#Processing_input).

The backslash is necessary to escape the number sign `#` in `"\#\#\#\#\#\#"`.

#### Only Vim

These commands replace new line by tab. If tab is present in the log, use another character instead of tab.

```
:%s/\n/\t/g
:%s/\t######/\r######/g
:g/^/m0
:%s/\t/\r/g
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a final newline at the end, the following command does what you want in Vim:

```
g/^###/.,/^$/m 0
```

Which searches for lines starting with `###` takes the range from `###` til the next blank line and moves it to the top.

If there is no final newline, it will probably abort with e.g. `E16: invalid range`, in that case you could adjust the regex like this:

```
g/^###/.,/\(^$\|\%$\)/m 0
```

However, du to the last line missing, the first entry won't have a new line afterwards, so after all it might be easier to just add a single empty line add the end and use the first command.

Comment: It is possible the range to go to another `######`, something like `:g/^###/,/^###/-1m 0`?
What is the purpose of the dot `.` in your code?

Comment: `:g/^###/;/\(\n###\|\%$\)/m0` worked for me.

Comment: the dot means explicit *this line*. Yes you can change the pattern to match other lines if you want